# Why does the sorting function not work in python for index slicing and how it can be done?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to sort a list  from a specific index to the last index so, i tried below code:

```
x=[4,3,6,1]
x[1::].sort()
print(x)
```

but resultant list was not sorted (means output was : `[4, 3, 6, 1]`)

So can someone tell me why is it happening so and how it can be done?

(Note: My expected output was `[4,1,3,6]`)

Comment: `x[1::].sort()` creates a brand-new list, and sorts it.  The new list is then immediately discarded, because there are no references to it.  You'd have to write something like `x[1:] = sorted(x[1:])`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your answer. I was unknown from the fact that `x[1::]` creates a new list...

Answer (score 1):

```py
x=[4,3,6,1]

#what x[1::].sort() did here
_y = x[1::] # create new list
_y.sort() #and sort the new list
del _y #but new list _y do not have reference to any variable.so it destroyed

#as jasonharper said.the sorted function return a variable then append to x
x[1:] = sorted(x[1::])
print(x)
```

```
[4, 1, 3, 6]
```

I just give details to jasonharper's answer